# 'Save PDF' function on dynamic page shows results from multiple iterations all overlapping

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

I have a PHP-based tool that dynamically generates a few paragraphs of content. I added a button to save your results to a PDF (using jsPDF). If you generate the content once, and hit the save button once, it works great. But if you generate and save multiple times, the PDF shows all generated results overlapping on top of each other.

Here's the project: [Generator](http://negatherium.com/npc-generator/) If you click the Generate button, then the save button (save it), then Generate one more time, and save one more time, you'll see what I mean.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js'> 
</script>


stuff


<script>

// Save page as PDF

var doc = new jsPDF();

var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    } };

$('#saveBtn').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#responseArea').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers });

    doc.save('npc.pdf');
});

</script>
```

The save button is supposed to produce a clean PDF. What seems to be happening is when you do it more than once, the new data is literally sitting on top of the old data without clearing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this issue: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2000

In the response they say they're no longer supporting `fromHTML` and `addHTML`

I would recommend using an alternative library like https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem.